# Why i can jump and than walk, and not walk and than jump. I don´t know what is wrong with the code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code I'm using on my character

- they can jump and walk
- but not walk and then jump.

I'm learning to use Unity and C #, so I take a code that already exists and work on it.

```cs
public CharacterController controller;
public Transform cam;

private Vector3 velocity;

public float gravity = -9.8f;
public float speed = 6f;
public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
public float velocidadePulo = 10.0f;

float turnSmoothVelocity;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Checa se as teclas W, A, S, D foram usadas
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    //Cria um vetor para guarda a direção a ser atualizda, o normalized faz com que
    //não se mova mais rápido na diagonal
    Vector3 direcao = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

    if (direcao.magnitude >= 0.1f)
    {
        //Personagem anda na direção do movimento
        float angloAlvo = Mathf.Atan2(direcao.x, direcao.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
        float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, angloAlvo, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

        //Aplica o movimento ao personagem
        Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angloAlvo, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
        controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    //Pulo
    if (controller.isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        velocity.y = velocidadePulo;
    }

    velocity.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "jump" and "walk" mean in this context. Could you describe the problem in terms of the code?  Which line of code is behaving unexpectedly, and what were you expecting?

Comment: All line of code is work propely, i'm work in a litle game/project and whem the character is walking that happe on the first if they can´t jump, that happen in the second if, but if u are jumping u can start walking. And i can´t find why this is happing

Comment: Oh, i find my error, the Character controller wasn´t touch the ground propaly.

Answer (score -1):

Turned out that the Character Controller wasn´t toucjing the graound properly.